# autoscroll JScrollPane disturbing

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane

I'm working on a text editor, the main panel is composed of 3 `JTextPane`s, 2 on the side which show the number of line and common syntax errors, and 1 in the middle for the main edition. The whole stuff is packed in a `JScrollPane`.

The autoscroll issue appears when the users jump a line (press ENTER), the `KeyListener`s attached add a new entry in the 2 sides `JTextPane`s (num and syntax error for the line),
in reaction, the `JScrollPane` autoscroll in the bottom of the docs, probably to show the new text inserted in the 2 sides `JTextPane`s.

I partially fix the problem by setting the `JScrollBar`'s position for each new line (added by the user) in my `KeyListener`s. Using scrollRectToVisible for example, or better by selecting a proper part of text in one of the 2 sides `JTextPane`s.

However, the final effect is not so great, for each new line the vertical scrollbar oscillates, and we can easily crash the app by pressing ENTER for a few seconds. I've been looking for solutions with a lot of methods of the JScrollPane class and trying `AdjustmentListener` but unsuccessfully. Would you help me?

PS: Sorry for my English. I am French, our forums suck.

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: You have three JTextPanes all inside of the same JScrollPane? I don't see that as being a good idea. Put each one in a seperate JScrollPane and see how it works.

Answer (score 0):

SSCCE great source of inspiration, as this one worked well (couldn't see my problem when running it) it seems that my method actually works, but was not running in the right listener in my real code.

Thanks anyway!
There is the SSCCE, its a simple JScrollPane composed of one central JTextPane for edition and one lateral for the lines number. The placeScroll() method place the scrollbar so the caret in the main JTextPane is in the middle (vertically) when the paneLigne try to push it down.
Bye

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextPane;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;

public class SSCCE extends JFrame {

    private JTextPane paneLigne, main;
    private String tempchain;

    public SSCCE() {

        this.setSize(500,500);
        this.setTitle("S");
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

        paneLigne = new JTextPane();
        paneLigne.setEditable(false);

        tempchain = "";
        for(int j=1; j<40; j++)
            tempchain+="  " + j + "  \n";
        paneLigne.setText(tempchain);


        main = new JTextPane();
        main.addKeyListener(new KeyListener() {

            private int lastnline=0;
            public void keyPressed(KeyEvent arg0) {

                if(arg0.getKeyCode()==10) {

                    String tecste=main.getText();
                    int n=nbLignes(tecste);

                    if(n>38) {
                        if(lastnline<n) {
                            paneLigne.setText(paneLigne.getText()+"  " + (n+1) + "  \n");
                        } else {
                            this.retablirLignes(tecste);
                        }
                    } else {
                        paneLigne.setText(tempchain);
                    }

                    lastnline=n;
                    this.placeScroll();
                }

            }

            @Override
            public void keyReleased(KeyEvent arg0) {    }

            @Override
            public void keyTyped(KeyEvent arg0) {   }



            private int nbLignes(String str) {
                int ret=1;
                for(int n=0, cpt=0; (n=str.indexOf('\n', cpt))!=-1; cpt=n+1)
                    ret++;
                return ret;
            }

            public void retablirLignes(String stret) {

                int n=this.nbLignes(stret);
                String retoure="";

                if(n>=40) {

                    for(int j=1; j<n+2; j++)
                        retoure+="  " + j + "  \n";
                    paneLigne.setText(retoure);

                }
                lastnline=n;
            }

            public void placeScroll() { 
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                if(paneLigne!=null) {

                    int n=this.nbLignesBuen(main.getText().substring(0, main.getCaretPosition()));
                    if(n!=-1) {
                        paneLigne.select(paneLigne.getText().indexOf(""+n), n+1);
                    } else {
                        paneLigne.select(0,1);
                    }

                }

            }

            private int nbLignesBuen(String str) { //return the index of the last 20th line
                int ret=0;
                for(int n, cpt=0; (n=str.indexOf('\n', cpt))!=-1; cpt=n+1)
                    ret++;
                if(ret>20)
                    ret-=20;
                else
                    ret=-1;
                return ret;
            }


        });

        JPanel contentpane=new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        contentpane.add(paneLigne, BorderLayout.WEST);
        contentpane.add(main, BorderLayout.CENTER);     

        this.setContentPane(new JScrollPane(contentpane));
        this.setVisible(true);

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        SSCCE fen = new SSCCE();

    }

}
```